# Onclick function adding and substracting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking for a way to reverse a function onclick.

This is the function

```
var theTotal = 0;


$('button').click(function(){
    theTotal = Number(theTotal) + Number($(this).val());
     $('.total').text(theTotal);    
});

$('.total').text(theTotal);
```

Now it adds a value inside the Div onclick but when its clicked again it should subtract the same value. How do I do this? This is the div:

```
<button class="grid__col--12 border-radius background--white box--shadow padding--medium margin-top--medium margin-top__sm" value="20">
<div class="grid__collapse">
    <div class="grid__col--8 grid__col--sm-12 text--left">
        <strong>
            <h6 class="module">Reserveringsmodule</h6>
        </strong>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__col--4 grid__col--sm-12 text--right color--pink">
        <p class="module">€20 per maand</p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__col--12 text--left margin-top">
        <p class="module">Mauris non tempor quam, et lacinia sapien. Mauris accumsan eros eget libero posuere vulputate. Etiam elit elit,
            elementum sed varius at, adipiscing vitae est. Sed nec felis pellentesque, lacinia dui sed, ultricies sapien.
            Pellentesque orci lectus, consectetur vel posuere posuere, rutrum eu ipsum.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this the only button you have to add/subtract something?

Comment: Are you going to have multiple buttons with different values?

Comment: The button should be able to add on first click, and substract the same value on the second click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a custom attribute for each button, saving the last operation made for said button:

Add the `data-operation` attribute to the element:

```
<button data-operation="subtract" value="20">
```

And then the jQuery;

```
 var theTotal = 0;

 $('button').click(function(){
     if($(this).data('operation') == "subtract"){
        theTotal = Number(theTotal) + Number($(this).val());
        $(this).data('operation', 'add');
     }else{
        theTotal = Number(theTotal) - Number($(this).val());
        $(this).data('operation', 'subtract');
     }
      $('.total').text(theTotal);    
  });
```

Comment: I agree with this solution also however if there are multiple buttons with different values then the lastOperation value for each button will need to be kept track of.

Comment: There will be multiple buttons with different values indeed

Comment: @JochemKroos Updated my answer, take a look.

Comment: @AmmoPT Thanks I'll try it out tomorrow!